Can we establish a chat room for plot?
Something I have wondered about since I cast my first close vote 7 years ago is, if we can't support questions about plot, and we can't, can we instead establish a permanent chat room; something like "Story Tellers Corner" where people can bring closed story-based and/or idea generation queries for less formal attention?
I don't know if this has been tried before, I never saw it if it was. I know that chat and Sandbox engagement has always been an issue in terms of quantity and also sometimes quality, which is why I'm not asking if this would be useful, we won't know unless we try it, or if it was tried in the past and has since gone, I'm just wondering if it's possible because I don't know enough about the chat room system to know what we can and can't do with it.

I don't think there is anything stopping you from starting a new room (see screenshot from this page). It's just a matter of getting people to use it.

"establish a permanent chat room" if by "permanent" you meant "cannot freeze", note that there's no such thing as permanent chat room.

There is generally no special permission needed to create chatrooms. They should still abide by CoC, of course, but the rules around what is an allowable room are loose.
I created Story Tellers Corner and made you the room owner. All that is left is for people to use it. The description (just so it is not blank) I put in is:

Place where people can bring closed story-based and/or idea generation queries for less formal attention


Here is my suggestion for next steps:

Advertise this room to people.
It will be good to come up with some guidelines for the room's operation. However, there is usually no need for much strictness. Not unless there is a lot of traffic. Until then the guidelines can just be there as a reminder how to use the room.
Feel free to read A guide to moderating chat and specifically the What tools are available to room owners? section. It probably sounds more imposing that it really is - it explains what tools you would have available and how to use them. It is nice to know your option. The room owner tools are rarely needed, in my experience.


Sure... go ahead.  That's what Chat is there for.
The only problem with Stackexchange Chat is that it is seriously lacking in visibility.  All the good intentions in the world aren't going to help unless  users know that it's there, and are willing to participate.
We have The Factory Floor... but there are a lot of metaphorical crickets in there.
